# Twilio user management api

Tags: rest, twilio, integration, twilio-api

Iam integrating Twilio with my app which displays the users in twilio account, and can add users, I also need billing related information(amount , due date etc) to be fetched from it through REST API, is there any resource that can help me with my requirements.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I think you need to share a lot more detail about the problem you are facing here. Have you read through the [Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/)? Where exactly are you having a problem?

Comment: in the documentation i find apis related to sending programmable voice, text and others which "implements" the services offered by Twilio. But what I need is a user management and account management kind of information, how many users are subscribed for Twilio, how to add new user and fetching upcoming bills, payment date and renewal kind of stuff using REST API

Comment: I think you may be looking for the [subaccount API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/api/subaccounts). Does that help?

Comment: i would like to explain my needs again, I don't want to use any of the services. my app just fetches the users and their count from Twilio and displays "x  number of ppl using Twilio under Y plan which expires in M days" , and i should be able to add users to Twilio not to any subaccounts of Twilio. is that possible with API

Comment: There’s no way to add users to Twilio without them signing up by themselves. We don’t have an API for the number of Twilio users, we report on user numbers in our quarterly earnings calls, and finally Twilio accounts are pay by usage, not a subscription. So I don’t think you can do what you want. I’d be interested to know what you are planning though.